# maya skeleton smooth bind acting weird

Tags: maya, modeling

I have a problem with rigging in maya. I have a skeleton that I smooth bound to the model. The normal position of the legs are this:

[image]

But when I move the controller on the left foot, the skin on the right leg moves along with it.

[image]

I have used a point constraint on the controller for the IK handle on the leg. I have tried weight painting the skin but it stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to apply the proper Skin Weights so that portion of your mesh doesn't move with the wrong joints.

Click on your Left ankle and foot joints at the normal position, and go to the  <kbd>Skin > Edit Smooth Skin > Paint Skin Weights Tool</kbd>.

The **Paint Skin Weights** tool tells the mesh where to deform with which joint. So I guarantee that if you click on that joint, you will see white on the wrong leg. Check it because with that little bit of movement, the color may not be a bright white, but a light gray or just enough so you don't notice it.

The best way I've found to clear up issues like these are to flood the area with black (no control), then gradually paint with white (full control) using the `Add`, not the `Replace` option. And don't paint where you can't see, like around corners, because you'll end up painting unwanted areas. Make sure you pan your camera around to see where you are painting.

[More information on Paint Skin Weights](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/CST_Paint_Skin_Weights_Tool.htm,topicNumber=d30e344964)